# Get current state value from a function declared in a hook scheduled to run later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Take the below code as an example.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


export default function Stopwatch(){
    const [stopwatch, setStopwatch] = useState(0);

    function updateStopwatch(){
        console.log("Updating stopwatch from ", stopwatch, " to ", stopwatch+1);
        setStopwatch(stopwatch + 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(updateStopwatch, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{stopwatch}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this code, the function `updateStopwatch` will be invoked periodically without depending on any re-rendering of the component ( Although its invocation will cause a re-render ) and each time it will be invoked, it needs to retrieve the current up-to-date value of the state variable stopwatch, so it can update it accordingly. So that the stop watch will keep counting up.

However, what happens is that it only gets the value of `stopwatch` at the moment the function is declared. It's not really subscribed to a state variable but more like it just reads a constant once. And as a result the count show 1 and is stuck there.

So how can I make such a function get an up-to-date value of a state variable whenever it's invoked?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of a stale closure over the initial `stopwatch` state value. Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly update from the previous state value instead of whatever value is closed over in callback scope at the time of execution. Move `updateStopwatch` declaration into the `useEffect` hook to remove it as an external dependency.

Example:

```
export default function Stopwatch(){
  const [stopwatch, setStopwatch] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function updateStopwatch(){
      setStopwatch(stopwatch => stopwatch + 1);
    }
    
    const interval = setInterval(updateStopwatch, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{stopwatch}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but can you please explain the line ```setStopwatch(stopwatch => stopwatch + 1);```  Are you providing a function as the argument for the function that sets the state? I didn't know we can do that!

Comment: @Menas Yes, it's a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). The `useState` state updater function can consume a new state value ***or*** a function that is called by React and passed the current state and is expected to return the next state value.

Answer (score 1):

In your **setState** method, you can retrieve a **prevState** argument, which is always the right value, here is the way you could do your function based on your example :

```
function updateStopwatch(){
    setStopwatch((prevState) => prevState + 1);
}
```